# How can I push a TabBar onto the navigation stack?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

From the `MainPage` defined in `AppShell.xaml` below, I want to be able to push a `TabBar` onto the navigation stack so that it will have a back button to return to the `MainPage`.

My AppShell.xaml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="MyApp.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:localize="clr-namespace:MyApp.Resources.Strings"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:xct="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Maui.Behaviors;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Maui"
    Shell.FlyoutHeaderBehavior="Default"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
    >

    <TabBar Route="SomeTabPage" x:Name="SomeTabBar">
            
        <Tab Route="OverviewTab" Title="{x:Static localize:Lang.Overview}" x:Name="OverviewTab">
            <ShellContent Route="OverviewPage"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:OverviewPage}"
                          />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="{x:Static localize:Lang.Alerts}" x:Name="AlertsTab">
            <ShellContent Route="AlertsPage"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AlertsPage}"
            />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>

    <ShellContent
        Route="MainPage"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        FlyoutItemIsVisible="False" 
        />

</Shell>
```

AppShell.xaml.cs has registration for the two routes used below. Not sure if the registration is part of the problem.

```
        Routing.RegisterRoute("ServiceAdvisorTabBar", typeof(TabBar));
        Routing.RegisterRoute("OverviewPageWithTabs", typeof(OverviewPage));
```

If I put a button in `MainPage` that pushes the OverviewTab onto the nav stack, it has no tabs, just a single OverviewPage:

```
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("/OverviewTab");
```

If I change that button to push the `TabBar` route of "SomeTabPage", it crashes.

```
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("/ServiceAdvisorTabBar");
```

That line is throwing a `System.NullReferenceException` exception.

```
    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in Android.Runtime.RuntimeNativeMethods.monodroid_debugger_unhandled_exception   C#
    0x1A in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper._unhandled_exception at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:13,5 C#
    0x1D in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:27,26    C#
    0x17 in System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw    C#
    0x6 in System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_0 C#
    0xC in Android.App.SyncContext. at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:36,19 C#
    0xE in Java.Lang.Thread.RunnableImplementor.Run at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36,6 C#
    0x8 in Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net8.0/android-34/mcw/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:84,4    C#
    0x8 in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:26,5  C#
```

Isn't there some way to push the `TabBar` over the `MainPage`?

Comment: First of all, the tabbar can't be added in the navigation stack. And according to your code, the tabbar and the mainpage are both root page for the appshell. So you can navigate by the flyout menu.

Comment: Why can't a TabBar view be added to the navigation stack? Is there no way to do that @LiyunZhang-MSFT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I concluded that there is no way to push a TabBar onto the navigation stack. TabBar items can only be defined as base views in the AppShell.xaml file. So I was able to navigate to the tab bar and put my own back button onto the TitleView so that it behaved as if it was pushed, but actually was a base view.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the `Navigation.NavigationStack`, it's type of `IReadOnlyList<Page`>. So you can't push a TabBar onto the navigation stack. You can only push the contentpage.

And you can use the flyout menu to navigate. In addition, you can also use the following code to navigate from mainpage to the OverviewPage with the tabbar.

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(OverviewPage)}");
```

Note: Please delete the

```
Routing.RegisterRoute("OverviewPageWithTabs", typeof(OverviewPage));
```

and keep

```
 <ShellContent Route="OverviewPage"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:OverviewPage}"/>
```

You declare two differnet route for the same page. And you should just declare one time. Plese void register the same route both in the xaml and code behind.

In addition, naviagting by this way will show the tabbar but without back button. Because they are both root page for the appshell.

Comment: Thank you. However, I need to show the tab bar with a back button. I have concluded that it is just not possible. So I made my own back button and it is getting the job done.